# React Web App- how to wrap 3 <div>s and return it on page

Tags: reactjs

I have made three cloud-shapes using css.
In App.js, I have wrapped the three `<div>`:

```
  <div className="cloud"> 
      <div className="cloud x1"></div>
        <div className="cloud x2"></div>
        <div className="cloud x3"></div>
  </div>
```

My question is, how to wrap these elements into a function and how to return on the page?

Answer (score 1):

This will work with React (also an example of a functional component):

```
import React from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  function getClouds() {
    return (
      <div className="cloud">
        <div className="cloud x1">Cloud 1</div>
        <div className="cloud x2">Cloud 2</div>
        <div className="cloud x3">Cloud 3</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getClouds()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: when I apply this into my code. It says ./src/App.js
  Line 112:36:  'getClouds' is not defined  no-undef